# raw mono 8 bit bytearray to jpeg using hardware accelaration

Tags: opencv, compression, hardware, jpeg

First thing I need to say is that I'm very very new to programming. And, I am stuck with a very stupid problem: I need to compress a Raw mono 8 bit bytearray grayscale image to Jpeg (to save space) at a rate of atleast 200FPS (realtime). Image size is 1280x1024px, so I need to process around 2.6Gigapixels per second! I tried using imagemagick, but it was unable to handle data at such high rates. I was just wondering if there is an efficient way to handle this. I can use GPU or CPU, whatever works best. I have no clue to how to get this done. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely give [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) a try. It features CPU accelerated processing (MMX, SSE2, or NEON) which gives impressive [performances](http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/About/Performance).